# Writing UUID to JSON in Scala with Spray

Tags: json, scala, uuid, spray

Im having some problems returning an `UUID` in a `JSON` with my application in `Scala` and `Spray`.
When the entity `User(id: UUID, name: String)` is parsed to `JSON` I received:

```
 {
     "id": {
         "mostSigBits": 1310448748437770800,
         "leastSigBits": -7019414172579620000
      },
      "name": "Sharekhan"
 }
```

I would like to receive the `uuid` in a `String format`. Something  like:

```
 {
     "id": "122fa631-92fd-11e2-9e96-0800200c9a63",
      "name": "Sharekhan"
 }
```

I defined the UUID format and the Read is executed when I parse from `JSON` to `User` but the Write isn't used in the inverse order (User -> Json)

```
 implicit object UuidJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[UUID] {
   def write(x: UUID) = JsString(x.toString) //Never execute this line
   def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
      case JsString(x) => UUID.fromString(x)
      case x           => deserializationError("Expected UUID as JsString, but got " + x)
   }
 }
```

Is any way to do this o should I convert the UUID into a String in the User entity?

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have the implicit format for the Uuid before the user format that uses it and it should work:

```
object UserJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
 implicit object UuidJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[UUID] {
   def write(x: UUID) = JsString(x.toString) //Never execute this line
   def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
      case JsString(x) => UUID.fromString(x)
      case x           => deserializationError("Expected UUID as JsString, but got " + x)
   }
 }
 implicit val UserFormat = jsonFormat2(User)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the code posted above is in this trait: `trait DefaultJsonFormats extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport with MetaMarshallers`

That I mix in my routes: `trait RootRouter extends Directives with DefaultJsonFormats`

Comment: Okey I think that I found the problem. The trait `RootRouter` parse the JSON to User but isn't this trait to do the parse from User to JSON. This conversion is in other class. I'm pretty sure that I should include this trait in this other class.

Comment: I think the usual Scala way is to put the case class that models the data and the json formatting objects into one class and then import them wherever they are used like the trait and anything that consumes data produced by the trait.

Comment: Yes, I do this but I have a problem: The actor who completes the RequestContext mix `Json4sSupport` because I need it to marshall the response. But this trait requires to define `val json4sFormats`. Now Im declaring this `val json4sFormats = DefaultFormats` and for this reason my UUID is write as I described above. Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: Can that problem be fixed by doing the imports at block level (instead of at the top) so that they don't overlap with each other?

Comment: No, that does not work for me :( I think that the problem is that with mix in with `Json4sSupport` I am declaring a new marshaller with `Default formats`. There are two ways to solve this: override or add formats to the `Json4sSupport` marshaller or use another marshaller. There must be a way to do the first thing but Im not able to find it.